# Display radio-buttons created in Js as a list-item (vertical list)

Tags: javascript, radio-button, vertical-alignment

I cannot figure out how to display vertically the radio-buttons with labels I have created dynamically with javascript. My radio-buttons appear in-line. Here is my code...
CSS / display: list-item; does not work...
Thanks for you help !

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var form = document.createElement("myForm");
for (i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
x=myArray[i];
addradiobutton("radio",x,"myForm");
}
function addradiobutton(type,text,formName) {
var label = document.createElement("label");
var element = document.createElement("input");
element.setAttribute("type", type);
element.setAttribute("value", text);
element.setAttribute("name", formName);
label.appendChild(element);
label.innerHTML += text;
var foo = document.getElementById(formName);
foo.appendChild(label);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addradiobutton() {
var result=""
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
 result+="<label>" + i + "</label><input type='radio' name='radio'>";
}
$('form').append(result);
}
```

Comment: this is one example using jquery with simple way..you can modify with your logic.

Comment: Thanks! however, as I am rather new on the topic (especially to jquery), I am not sure I understand how this all works.

Comment: Should I replace the code inside my addradiobutton function by your code ? Why i<3 ? - sorry for my questions :)

Comment: it is upto you..how many radiobuttons need to be generated? provide there .

Comment: Sorry again.The $ sign generates an error in my code. I am certainly missing something...

Comment: Any possibilities using Javascript only ?